# Работа со сканером штрих-кода без поля ввода данных

Tags: c#, wpf

Уважаемые знатоки, прошу Вашей помощи. Мне понадобилось добавить в своё WPF приложение возможность работать со сканером штрих-кода. Сканер работает в режиме USB-HID. Основной нюанс заключается в том, что поля для ввода штрих-кода нет. При сканировании, должно произойти событие, вне зависимости от места нахождения фокуса.
Вариант с TextBox я пробовал, он работает, но не подходит.
Поскольку сканер эмулирует клавиатуру, а подписался на событие:

`this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnButtonKeyDown);`

Но дальше результата вменяемого не получается…

```
private void OnButtonKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {                 
        string shtrihKodInput = e.Key.ToString();

    }
```

Вместо ожидаемого значения переменной в виде номера шк,при отладке, я получаю почему-то кусок штрих-кода в коде! и значение переменной `shtrihKodInput` = System. (это я так понимаю нажатие клавиши Enter, которое идёт после удачного чтения штрих-кода)

Работающих примеров, которые можно было бы от препарировать и разобраться – я не нашёл.

Помогите, пожалуйста, советом!
Спасибо!

**UPD:**
Благодаря Вашим советам, идеям и подсказкам, я нашёл статью http://www.dylansweb.com/tag/user32/ которая оказалась рабочей, на примере которой можно двигаться дальше. Единственное, смущает результат, который я получаю при считывании штрих-кода : `LeftAltNumPad0NumPad4NumPad9LeftAltNumPad0NumPad4NumPad9LeftAltNumPad0NumPad4NumPad8LeftAltNumPad0NumPad5NumPad2LeftAltNumPad0NumPad5NumPad5LeftAltNumPad0NumPad5NumPad6LeftAltNumPad0NumPad4NumPad9LeftAltNumPad0NumPad4NumPad8LeftAltNumPad0NumPad4NumPad9LeftAltNumPad0NumPad5NumPad3Return`
Хотя сам штрих-код такой : `1104781015`

Почему так получается?

Comment: Слушайте порт на котором работает сканер и перехватывайте данные. На мой взгляд так будет проще.

Comment: Так можно, если включена эмуляция USB-COM, но мне бы не хотелось так делать...

Comment: почему? Кто мешает вам слушать usb порт?

Comment: Можно повесить глобальный слушатель клавиатуры на форму, и ловить нажатия. (в WinAPI это SetWindowHookEx, в wpf думаю что-то подобное есть)

Comment: Слушаем приложением клавиатуру (не важно каким способом) если частота "нажатий" поднимается выше определенной рамки (т.к. сканер передает "нажатия" клавиш с довольно большой частотой) то читаем что он передал и передаем на обработку. Если формат передаваемых данных стандартизирован и передает отчетливые начало и конец, то это упрощает обнаружение данных.

Comment: @nick_n_a Знать бы ещё как его найти, этот глобальный слушатель... За идею - спасибо!

Comment: @Геннадий П Видел примеры с таймером, да. Но попытки "запустить" код успешными не оказались :( Продолжу в этом направлении поиски. Спасибо!

Comment: За слушателя, зайдите в msdn SetWindowHookEx - вот http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644984(v=VS.85).aspx  Если ваше приложение активно - можно ставить фильтр на клаву - сработает. Можно погуглить - думаю на с# этот фокус портировали.

Comment: Вроде вот http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread965089.html достаточно. Если мало, то сюда http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C